# Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException - When Unit Testing

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle

I am trying to unit test an Orchestrator.

```
//Arrange
var containter = new WindsorContainer();
var Orch = containter.Resolve<ApiOrchestrator>();// Exception Thrown here
```

The Constructor for the Orchestrator is:

```
public ApiOrchestrator(IApiWrap[] apiWraps)
{
    _apiWraps = apiWraps;
}
```

The registration is

```
public class IocContainer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<FrmDataEntry>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<ApiOrchestrator>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IApiWrap>().ImplementedBy<ClassA>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IApiWrap>().ImplementedBy<ClassB>().LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

The IocContainer is in the project being tested but the namespace is referenced and I can `new` up an Orchestrator. I want it to just give me the array of all registered IApiWrap.

Being new to Castle I don't understand what's missing. Code fix would be nice, but I'd really like to know why the container doesn't seem to have the orchestrator registered.

Comment: So I think that I am missing a call to the install method from the container, but I'm not sure what to use as an IWindsorInstaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so 3 things are missing

1. A reference to Castle.Windsor.Installer
2. A call from container to installer to 'go look for' all of the registered classes.
3. The installer also needed to add a sub resolver to make a collection of the classes since a specific collection was not registered and a Collection of IApiWrap is required by the orchestrator.

The Installer change

```
public class IocContainer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        //New Line
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(
                  new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel, true));

        container.Register(Component.For<FrmDataEntry>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<ApiOrchestrator>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IApiWrap>().ImplementedBy<SettledCurveImportCommodityPriceWrap>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IApiWrap>().ImplementedBy<ForwardCurveImportBalmoPriceWrap>().LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

The Test / Resolving Change

```
//Arrange
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        //New Line
        container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("","EkaA*") ));

        var Orch = container.Resolve<ApiOrchestrator>();
```

Now it works, though any further explanation or correction of what the code is doing is welcome.